# Program excel to return a specific value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that is going to be used in a survey.

How can I make the cells only to return "x" regardless of what the survey taker type in.

For instance, if I write a "w" in the cell, it should turn into an "x".

I have come to a point where I think there is an option when I protect the workbook or sheet. Because I can tell from another spreadsheet (which has this function) that it only works if the workbook is protected.

I tried to google it, but it seems as if I don't know the right keywords to find the answer.

Also, I have found a set of Vba code that I fiddle with, but I'm not sure this is correct. I don't want to attach the code as I don't want to confuse any response here.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but this sounds like a job for [data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211485).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in the worksheet module and test it out, when you change a cell in column A (1) it will activate,

Where is the worksheet Module?

[image]

Copy and paste the code ,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1,B1,C1,A4,B4,C4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = 0
    If Target <> "" Then Target = "X"
    Application.EnableEvents = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 

Question, how am I supposed to use this code for specific cells?

Right now it's automatically applicable to A column.

Comment: I get how to change columns inside here:

 `If Target.Column = 1 Then`

But it seems as if I cant choose to set specific cells.

Comment: `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1,A3,B3,B5,C1,C6")) Then`

This string has an error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

I'll try to debug it.

Comment: Works like a charm! Millions of thanks! I will send this topic to a few of my coworkers so they can use this code too, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you (just change the range to the one you need) :

```
Option Explicit
Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   On Error GoTo errorbutler 'error handler - important to have this in case your macro does a booboo
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn off automatic calculation to speed up the macro
Application.EnableEvents = False 'turn off events in order to prevent an endless loop
Dim LR, cell As Range 'Declare your variables
Set LR = Range("A1:b3") ' Select range of cells this macro would apply to
    For Each cell In Target 'Loops through the cells that user have changed
        If Union(cell, LR).Address = LR.Address Then 'Checks if the changed cell is part of your range
           cell.Value="x" 'changes the value of that cell to x
        End if
    Next cell

Errorexit: 'part of error handling procedure

Application.EnableEvents = True 'Turn autocalc back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'turn events back on

Exit Sub

Errorbutler:          'error handling procedure
 Debug.Print Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
 Resume Errorexit

End Sub
```

Oh yes, and this code should be put into the worksheet module - the same way as Dave has shown you

Comment: Thank You very much! I will use this code in addition to Dave's I have a very large spreadsheet and they will both come in handy!

Comment: `Set LR = Range("A1:b3")`

LR variable is not defined, and it returns an error, unfortunately.

Comment: @RobinWiman `Dim LR, cell As Range` - this line declares the variables. there was an extra comma in there, sorry about that.